# Creating dataframe by adding new letter in the combination in r

Tags: r, dataframe, combinations

I have to create a dataframe with character combination. I have 3 characters such as x1, x2 and x3. Code of my previous dataframe was-

```
gain<-do.call(rbind, lapply(2:3, function(x) {
   do.call(rbind, combn(3, x, function(y) {
    data.frame(A = paste(y, collapse = ""),
               B = paste(c("", y), collapse = "x"),
               stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
}, simplify = FALSE))
}))


 > gain
   A      B
1  12   x1x2
2  13   x1x3
3  23   x2x3
4 123 x1x2x3
```

Now the problem is that I have to include a new letter "b" similar to "x" in the 2nd column with this combination separated with "+" sign. My desired output is

```
> gain
   A      B
1  12   b1x1+b2x2
2  13   b1x1+b3x3
3  23   b2x2+b3x3
4 123 b1x1+b2x2+b3x3
```

I could not manage it. I will be grateful if anyone helps me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option with `strsplit` and `paste`

```
gain$B <- sapply(strsplit(gain$B, "(?<=\\d)(?=x)", perl = TRUE), 
   function(x) paste(paste0("b",
     unlist(regmatches(x, gregexpr("\\d+", x)))), x, collapse="+", sep=""))


gain$B
#[1] "b1x1+b2x2"      "b1x1+b3x3"      "b2x2+b3x3"      "b1x1+b2x2+b3x3"
```

---

Or an option with `gsub`

```
gsub("(x)(\\d+)", "b\\2\\1\\2", gsub("(?<=\\d)(?=x)", "+", gain$B, perl = TRUE))
#[1] "b1x1+b2x2"      "b1x1+b3x3"      "b2x2+b3x3"      "b1x1+b2x2+b3x3"
```

#### data

```
gain <- structure(list(A = c(12L, 13L, 23L, 123L), B = c("x1x2", "x1x3", 
"x2x3", "x1x2x3")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4"))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
tmp = gsub("(x(\\d))", "b\\2\\1\\+", gain$B)
substring(tmp, 1, nchar(tmp) - 1)
#[1] "b1x1+b2x2"      "b1x1+b3x3"      "b2x2+b3x3"      "b1x1+b2x2+b3x3"
```

Or if you want to start from `A`

```
tmp = gsub("(\\d)", "b\\1x\\1\\+", gain$A)
substring(tmp, 1, nchar(tmp) - 1)
#[1] "b1x1+b2x2"      "b1x1+b3x3"      "b2x2+b3x3"      "b1x1+b2x2+b3x3"
```